# Why is it dangerous to create instances of MemoryCache?

Tags: c#, memorycache

In the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Runtime_Caching_MemoryCache__ctor_System_String_System_Collections_Specialized_NameValueCollection_) for the constructor of `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`, it says:

> Caution: Do not create MemoryCache instances unless it is required. If you create cache instances in client and Web applications, the MemoryCache instances should be created early in the application life cycle. You must create only the number of cache instances that will be used in your application, and store references to the cache instances in variables that can be accessed globally.

A quick glance at the decompiled source doesn't reveal anything unusual that would warrant this warning (apart from not creating an instance unless it's required, but that's pretty trivial).

What can go wrong if you instantiate `MemoryCache` while the application is up and running? What can go wrong if the instance is not referenced by a global variable (and instead e.g. managed within a singleton service)?

Comment: Implicit in usage, the memory cache is expected to require a lot of memory.  You would not want to create one for every web page request for example.  The ideal number of instances is one, whether you wrap it in a singleton is of no concern.  But that's already done by MemoryCache.Default, you might was well use it and be sure it can't get out of hand.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by "implicit in usage"? Surely if I create my own instance of `MemoryCache`, it doesn't get used implicitly?

Comment: Because a memory cache uses memory I'd guess. If you created one per user (as an example) you'd kill performance

Comment: @Liam But that's obvious, isn't it? I'm just wondering why it's stated explicitly here and not e.g. for `Dictionary`. This vague warning suggests to me that I should implement my own cache with sliding expiration to avoid strange things happening.